# Do I still need to create another use state to render each object in react js?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, object

[image]

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const getWeather = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${process.env.API_KEY}&q=${input}&aqi=yes`
    );
    const res = await data.json();
    console.log(res);
    setData(res);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getWeather();
    setInput("");
  };
```

Do I still need to create another state if there many objects? or how to put the current and location inside the data?

Comment: It's up to you. You can have one state object that represents the response or have a state for each. I'd probably just use one state and call `setData(res)`. Probably would not start with initial value of empty array though.

Comment: Depends on what you are gonna do with this objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to put more property inside any object of array:

```
setData(oldData=>{
   return oldData.map(od=>({...od, current:val1, location: val2}))
})
```